# NHibernate transform sql query to NHibernate QueryOver query

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

So I have a bit of a SQL query which I am not sure how to convert to NHibernate syntax

```
cast(case when count(distinct order) > 1 then count(distinct order) * -1 else max(order.orderId) end as int)
```

I currently have the following NHibernate code:

```
projectionList.Add(
    Projections.Conditional(
        Restrictions.Gt(Projections.CountDistinct(() => orderDto), 1),
            Projections.CountDistinct(() => orderDto), // TODO: * -1
            Projections.Max(() => orderDto.orderId)
    )
);
```

As you can see, I am not sure how to do the `* -1` part? Has somebody any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SQLFunctionTemplate` and `Projections.SqlFunction` to express any complex SQL that needs projection parameters. In your case you can do something like this:

```
    //All projections parameters in template are replaced with placeholders like ?1 ?2 ?3...
    //If possible move it to static field to avoid template parsing on each execution
    var yourTemplate = new SQLFunctionTemplate(
        NHibernateUtil.Int32, //Template result
        "cast(case when ?1 > 1 then ?1 * -1 else ?2 end as int)");

    //And in you query use the following projection:
    Projections.SqlFunction(
        yourTemplate,
        null, 
        Projections.CountDistinct(() => orderDto), //?1 in template
        Projections.Max(() => orderDto.orderId) //?2 in template
        );
```